# Grouping in a namespace vs. prefixing Classes

Tags: architecture, naming-conventions, namespaces, naming, prefix

imagine a situation where you have an application that needs to import data from different sources. For each of these sources exists a seperate model (often not related to the others).

So let's say i have my software component X which does all the importing, the namespace is correspondingly X. In X i have all my different parsers and importers, so maybe one for txt files, another for xls files etc.

Which style do you prefer:

```
X.XlsParser
X.XlsModelObject
X.TxtParser
X.TxtModelObject
```

vs.

```
X.Xls.Parser
X.Xls.ModelObject
X.Txt.Parser
X.Txt.ModelObject
```

or should i just put the model (2-4 entities) for the corresponding source into a sub namespace?

```
X.XlsParser
X.Xls.ModelObjectA
X.Xls.ModelObjectB
X.TxtParser
X.Txt.ModelObjectA
X.Txt.ModelObjectB
```

I don't want to clutter a single namespace with all those unrelated classes, however i also don't want to have issues like figuring out which parser my code is referencing (would have to look usings).

What do you think about

```
X.Xls.XlsParser
```

some kind of doubles the work.

What naming conventions do you adhere to?

Comment: What languages are we talking about?

Comment: c# in this case, might also be any of the c family (c, c++, c#, objective-c, java..)

Comment: It couldn't be C though... it doesn't have namespaces.

Comment: objective-c doesn't have namespaces either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I prefer the second style (e.g. `X.Xls.Parser`). I like to keep separate components as separated as I can.

It also depends on how closely related these components are. If they are very closely related, they should be in the same namespace.

Answer (score 2):

I would go for your last option:

```
Xls.XlsParser
Csv.CsvParser
```

This is similar to ADO.NET conventions

```
SqlClient.SqlConnection
OracleClient.OracleConnection
```

That way, your related classes are grouped by namespaces, but if you import 2 namespaces you don't need to differentiate by explicitly prefixing with the namespace in your code.

Comment: Excel can deal with file formats other than .xls, and so for a parser specifically for .xls files I'd use Xls.

Answer (score 1):

For this I would probably have

```
X.Excel.Parser
X.Excel.ModelObject
X.Csv.Parser
X.Csv.ModelObject
```

and maybe

```
X.Core.ParserBase
```

or

```
X.IParser
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

I would also vote for using namespaces.  That's what they are for.

Intellisense will be more useful if you break things up into namespaces.